# How to stop Mosquitto service running under macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, service, mosquitto

Under macOS Big Sur I started a Mosquitto broker service from the command line:

```
/usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -c /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

Now I would like to change the `mosquito.conf` file and check for changes.

My issue is that if I execute the same command again, I get the following status messages:

```
1615884201: mosquitto version 2.0.9 starting
1615884201: Config loaded from /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1615884201: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1615884201: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1615884201: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1615884201: Error: Address already in use
```

Furthermore, I cannot see any mosquitto service (e.g. by `ps aux | grep mosquitto`).

Where is the process hidden and how do I stop it?

Comment: I found the issue: the Error "Address already in use" was not due to a process running in the background. The reason for this was that I used bind_address 0.0.0.0 in my `mosquitto.conf`which was used elsewhere. By changing this address to the ip of my machine, the mosquitto process starts and is visible in the process list.

Answer (score 2):

You have to type in terminal:
`pkill mosquitto`

Answer (score 1):

You select the terminal that mosquitto is running in and then press and hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key while press <kbd>c</kbd>.

If you've managed to launch mosquitto in the background you can use `ps` to find the process id and then use `kill <pid>` to stop the broker.

You can only run one instance at a time that uses the same port numbers on any given interface.

Binding to `0.0.0.0` is just short hand for bind to all interfaces, but it's still going to be dependant on which port numbers you are using.